# sed does not work when included in script

Tags: bash, sed

I have got a list of public dns (in a file called dns.test).It looks like some of its elements do not resolve. I need to eliminate them. Here is the file:

```
199.255.137.34
103.112.162.165
103.133.222.202
82.146.26.2
94.236.218.254
185.81.41.81
103.209.52.250
119.160.80.164
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
151.80.222.79
```

note: there is no blanks, trailing or heading spaces.

I made a snippet to check them one by one and remove the faulty ones:

```
while IFS='\n' read -r LINE;do dig +short +timeout=1 serverfault.com @${LINE} &>/dev/null;[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "${LINE} -> OK" || { echo "${LINE} -> NOK";sed -i "s/${LINE}//g" dns.test; };done< <(cat dns.test)
```

I shorten the timeout otherwise it's the hell slow!

but the sed part does not work; I base the sed part of the snippet on the following test:

```
LINE=199.255.137.34;sed -i "s/${LINE}//g" dns.test  #-> this works manually but not when included in the script.
```

thankx folks!!

Comment: Is your goal here to *remove* the DNS servers that can't be used, or to make their lines blank?

Comment: `IFS='\n'` means `IFS` characters are ``\`` and `n`. You don't need to set or unset the `IFS` here.

Comment: Also, you're modifying the file while you're reading from the same file.

Comment: When asking for help with your code, cramming it all onto 1 line so it's as hard as possible for everyone else to read is going to reduce how many people are willing to try to understand it so we can help. Please format your code legibly, i.e. with line breaks and indenting at least, when posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `sed` is superfluous for this task. Simply print out the addresses of the working dns servers and replace the content of the original file with the output. You can try this:

```
while read -r ipaddr; do
    dig +short +timeout=1 serverfault.com @"$ipaddr" &>/dev/null && echo "$ipaddr"
done < dns.test > working-dns.test
```

and `mv working-dns.test dns.test` if the contents of the `working-dns.test` look  fine.

Comment: @ Nejat: Now I see it, yes that's obvious.

Comment: @ Ed: absolutely. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, and please notice the usage of char '<' and '>' .

```
LINE="199\.255\.137\.34";sed -i "/\<$LINE\>/d" dns.test
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for that usage of `-i` and the word boundaries.

Comment: @EdMorton .. FWIW, `-i` (albeit with an optarg) and word boundaries work in FreeBSD (and possibly other BSDs) as well. It might be wiser to refer to these extensions as "non-standard" rather than "requires GNU sed".

Comment: @ghoti I know, that's why I said `for that usage of -i` rather than just `for -i` since the backup file name isn't optional in BSD sed, just in GNU sed.